# segmentation fault when trying to read video using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, coredump

i am trying to read video using opencv2.4.13. The code is written in cpp. The "Segmentation fault (core dump) error occurred at the `video_capture=  cv::VideoCapture(video_fname);`. Please advise. Thanks

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("must provide one command argument with the video file or stream to open\n");
        return 1;
    }
    std::string video_fname;
    video_fname = std::string(argv[1]);
    cv::VideoCapture video_capture;
    bool from_camera = false;
    if(video_fname == "0") {
       video_capture = cv::VideoCapture(0);
       from_camera = true;
    } else {
       std::cout<<"i am here"<<std::endl;

       video_capture=  cv::VideoCapture(video_fname);
    }


    if(!video_capture.isOpened()) {

       fprintf(stderr, "could not open video %s\n", video_fname.c_str());
       video_capture.release();
       return 1;
    }
}

....
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does video_fname contains?

Comment: Hi @api55, video_fname contains the path of my video file

Comment: @JetHerngChion what codec is the video encoded with ? what OS are you using ? What was the OpenCV cmake config for the build you're using (e.g. is it using ffmpeg for video decoding, gstreamer, etc. ?)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza the video is mp4 and avi. Using ubuntu16.04, opencv2.4.13, ffmpeg 4.1.3, gcc 5.4.0. The ffmpeg is for video conversion if not mistaken, basically i follow the guide here https://github.com/andreanobile/opencv_ffmpeg_streaming, which is to stream out video to RTMP.

Comment: @JetHerngChion I understand you have ffmpeg installed, but is opencv compiled with ffmpeg support ? I'm not sure what build tools you have installed and where opencv lives on your system, but can you try something like this:`ldd /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so`. Not 100% the command will work, but the idea is to list the dependencies of OpenCV HighGUI module to see if was compiled with ffmpeg support (e.g. if the command doesn't run you'll need to tweak/find the equivalent for your system setup)